# To evaluate the surface integral $\iint_S(x\,dy\,dz+y\,dx\,dz+z\,dx\,dy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

How to evaluate the surface integral

$$\iint_S(x\,dy\,dz+y\,dx\,dz+z\,dx\,dy)$$

where $S$ is the outer surface of the ellipsoid

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

that lie above the $xy-$plane.

My thought was to substitute $x=a \sin\theta \cos\psi, y=b \sin\theta \sin\psi, x=c \cos\theta$, where $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq \psi\leq 2\pi$. But in this way i got the answer as $-abc\pi$, which is suppose to be $2abc\pi$. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My steps

$$\frac{\delta(x,y)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}=ab\sin\theta \cos\psi$$
$$\frac{\delta(y,z)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}=bc\sin^2\theta \cos \psi$$
$$\frac{\delta(z,x)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}=ac\sin^2\theta \sin \psi$$

The given integral

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(x\frac{\delta(y,z)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}+y\frac{\delta(z,x)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}+z\frac{\delta(x,y)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)})\,d\theta\, d\psi$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\sin \theta)\,d\theta\, d\psi$$

$$=-abc\pi$$

Comment: Apply divergence theorem

Comment: You will not even need an integral if you know the formula for ellipsoid volume

Comment: I was suppose to do it manually by substituting the value of $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: Then you must share your working on how you got $- \pi abc$. We can check where you made a mistake.

Comment: Ok. It will take sometime.

Comment: Sure no problem. Please ping once you edit.

Comment: @MathLover Done. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in $\frac{\delta(x,y)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}=ab\sin\theta \cos\psi$.

It should be $\frac{\delta(x,y)}{\delta(\theta,\psi)}=ab\sin\theta \cos\theta$

Also you must write the order of integral correctly given $0 \leq \psi \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

This is the integral you should finally get:

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} abc \sin\theta \ d\theta \ d\psi = 2 \pi abc$

Comment: Now i got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

By the Gauss-Ostrogradsky divergence theorem the surface integral ∯xdydz+ydxdz+zdxdy is equal to the integral ∫∫∫(div(xi+yj+zk)dxdydz which is equal to ∫∫∫(∂x/∂x+∂y/∂y+∂z/∂z)dxdydz =3∫∫∫dxdydz=3V where V is the volume of the ellipsoid well known to be 4/3π(abc)^1/2. Therefore the triple integral is 4π(abc)^1/2 but since only the upper half is asked we get 2π(abc)^1/2. We must notice that the ellipsoid as it is given is NOT in the usual form with squares in the denominators so we get a result with square root of abc. I cant make it clearer!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).